# How to force Bootstrap's navigation bar to stay in inline position?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navigation bar for the bottom of the webpage and it's working fine with the "md-viewport" but i find it difficult to maintain this navigation bar in inline position in "xs viewport" as it's "li" tags are stacking up on each other and i wish to prevent this blocked structure. How may i do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TATTOO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta class="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css"></link>-->
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
     <nav class="navbar">
      <div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-left: 230px;">
        <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>PRICE</kbd></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>GALLERY</kbd></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>MEDIA</kbd></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>FAQs</kbd></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>CONTACT US</kbd></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </nav><!-- navigation bar 2 -->
   </div><!-- col-md-8 -->
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `list-inline`..

```
<ul class="navbar-nav list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>PRICE</kbd></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>GALLERY</kbd></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>MEDIA</kbd></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>FAQs</kbd></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-right:0px !important;"><kbd>CONTACT US</kbd></a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/RKrH4WD6hE

Comment: Woah! Thanks, Even after knowing about this class i was unable to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Your float:left; is not set if the min-width is below 768px.
This is what Chrome shows me:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
navbar.less:273
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```

Remove that and you'll be fine

Edit:
As an alternative, you could add a class to every li and give that float:left

```
<li class="floatme"></li>
```

and in your style

```
.floatme {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: My other css stylings won't allow this. Anyways, thank you for replying. My problem is now solved. :)